# display issue with pygame in python3

Tags: python, macos, pygame, atom-editor

[This is the output of my code. I can't figure out how to fix this issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQKzI.jpg)
This code is showing weird lines in the window created using Pygame.
I was learning about using arrow keys in Pygame and con not get rid of this glich in the window.
The code that I made changes to is on geeks for geeks here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-drawing-design-using-arrow-keys-in-pygame/
This works just fine but when I use a different sized window and a different shape to draw it shows the weird lines in the window.

```
import pygame
import tkinter

pygame.init()

# create the display surfce object of specific dimensions (1000x1000).
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# Setting the window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Dungen World")

# Current coordinates
x = 250
y = 250

# dimensions of the player
width = 10
height = 10

# Speed of movement
vel = 2.5

# Indicator that pygame is running
running = True

# Main game loop
while running:
    # Time delay(milliseconds)
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    # Iterate over the list of event objects
    # that was returned by the pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # if event object type is QUIT
        # then quitting the pygame
        # and program both
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # This will exit the while loop
            running = False

    # Stores the key pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        x -= vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        x += vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        y -= vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        y += vel

    # drawing the square on screen
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y), width/2)

    # To refresh the window
    pygame.display.update()

# Closes the pygame window
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. Does anything change if you call `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()`?

Comment: Runs fine on my Linux machine. Might be a macOS issue?

Comment: Seems like a macOS graphics issue. If you use newer version of python + pygame is the problem still there? for me on windows, python2.7/3.6/3.8 this works fine

Comment: still having the same problem with pygame.display.flip()

Comment: Updated everything and it still dosen't work, probably a macOS graphics issue!

Answer (score 0):

Add `win.fill((0, 0, 0))` (or whatever background color you want) at the beginning of your game loop. For some reason, macOS freaks out if the background doesn't have a color.

Your code should look like this:

```py
import pygame
import tkinter

pygame.init()

# create the display surfce object of specific dimensions (1000x1000).
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# Setting the window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Dungen World")

# Current coordinates
x = 250
y = 250

# dimensions of the player
width = 10
height = 10

# Speed of movement
vel = 2.5

# Indicator that pygame is running
running = True

# Main game loop
while running:
    # Time delay(milliseconds)
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    # Fill entire window with black
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Iterate over the list of event objects
    # that was returned by the pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # if event object type is QUIT
        # then quitting the pygame
        # and program both
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # This will exit the while loop
            running = False

    # Stores the key pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        x -= vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        x += vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        y -= vel

    # If left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height:
        # Decrement in x coordinates
        y += vel

    # drawing the square on screen
    pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y), width/2)

    # To refresh the window
    pygame.display.update()

# Closes the pygame window
pygame.quit()
```

**Edit:**
Without this piece of code, the player doesn't actually "move" and acts more like a drawing app than a game.